# How to use DCharts in Vaadin with Java

Tags: java, spring, methods, components, vaadin

I created method (component) in java with Vaadin like below:

```
public VerticalLayout createDchart(){

        VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();

        DataSeries dataSeries = new DataSeries();
        dataSeries.add(3,8,6);


        SeriesDefaults seriesDefaults = new SeriesDefaults();
        seriesDefaults.setRenderer(SeriesRenderers.BAR);

        Axes axes = new Axes();
        axes.addAxis(
         new XYaxis().setRenderer(AxisRenderers.CATEGORY)
         .setTicks(new Ticks().add("a", "b","c"))   
        );


        Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter();
        highlighter.setShow(false);

        Options options = new Options();
        options.setSeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults);
        options.setAxes(axes);
        options.setHighlighter(highlighter);


        DCharts dCharts = new DCharts();
        dCharts.setDataSeries(dataSeries);
        dCharts.setOptions(options);
        dCharts.show();

        verticalLayout.add(dCharts);
        
        

        return verticalLayout;

    }
```

But I have some errors like:

"The type com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

and

"The type com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Somebody can help me?

Comment: What Vaadin version are you using and what is DCharts ?

Comment: I am using vaadin V23, dCharts is a free library to creating charts

Comment: The class name `com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent` is referring to either Vaadin 7 or 8. So you probably are trying to use old library that is not compatible with Vaadin 23.

Comment: I found newest version in maven repo

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.vaadin.addons/dcharts-widget -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
    <artifactId>dcharts-widget</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Unforunately that [latest version](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/dcharts-widget) is already 9 years old and not compatible with Vaadin 23.

Comment: Somebody know some free library for creating charts in vaadin ?

Comment: Go to vaadin.com/directory and use search keyword 'chart'. There are four add-ons compatible with at least Vaadin 14, some of those may work with Vaadin 23, but you need to test that.

Answer (score -1):

I am now using SoCharts from add-ons. It works with SoCharts 3.0.0 with Vaadin 23.0.8 and Java 17. One remark, you must add com.storedobject to vaadin.whitelisted-packages in application.properties if you are using Spring Boot Maven project.